# Forcing a verbose fsck on reboot (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, rackspace, fsck

I'd like to force a verbose `fsck` on reboot of my Ubuntu linux server, I can get `fsck` to run on reboot by creating a file `/forcefsck` in my root dir ...

Additionally, by adding a `y` into the contents of the `/forcefsck` file my server will (properly) run `fsck` on reboot without any user interaction but every time I reboot (and let the auto fsck run) and then do ...

`fsck -nvf /dev/somedisk`

I still have the disk errors I had before, I even tried putting `yvf` in the text of the `/forcefsck` file with no luck.

Is there a simple way for me to force a verbose `fsck` on reboot?

***Note***: I've watched the `fsck` running at reboot and it does not come up with the same errors I get when I run `fsck -nvf /dev/somedisk` ?

**Update:** This is a remote server ...

Comment: What't the root fs? ext2/3/4?

Comment: The root fs is `ext3`

Answer (score 3):

The `/forcefsck` file's contents isn't examined anywhere only the presence in the script `/etc/init/mountall.conf` and itf this file is present then the `--force-fsck` option is added to the `mountall` program. It's `man` is a bit short but if you run `mountall --help` then it shows that it has a `--verbose` option. You can change the `/etc/init/mountall.conf` file to run the mountall with `--verbose` option maybe it will show you more. Not sure, I haven't tried it myself.

But the best if you **just boot the system from a LiveCD and repair your filesystem from there**.

Comment: I will look into this, thanks ... for the record this is a remote machine so I can't use LiveCD ...

Comment: You can write a custom startup script to run before mountall to do fsck for you with your desired options.

Comment: Where would this startup script go? Is there a `rc runlevel` that I can know will fire before the root filesystem is mounted?

Comment: Also of interest I saw here http://askubuntu.com/a/151742/4153 that `/etc/default/rcS` sets `$FSCKFIX` which is a variable used in the `mountall.conf` to set `fsck` "fix" errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a mistake on your command ...
Check again fsck parameters on man: -n is for not updating! 
I'll try instead:

fsck -v /dev/somedisk

Comment: `fsck -nvf /dev/somedisk` is being used to *check* the disk for errors **after** the "forced" check is run ... it's not the command that is used to do the `fsck` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `fsck` of / filesystem, I can recommend you boot from Ubuntu install CD and on the basic screen choose 'Rescue mode'. You will have a basic system and from rescue you can do `fsck` of filesystem safely.

Another chance is, when you change in file `/etc/default/rcS` variable `FSCKFIX` to `yes`: it will run fsck on the filesystems with `-y` option.

Comment: Thanks, but this is on a remote server so I don't have that option ....

Comment: @JustinJenkins please, check my answer - I've added another one advice.